# Plotting a 3D Plot from a Pandas CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, 3d

So I have a pandas data frame that looks like the following:

```
Time         Velocity       Cxx
-1.0         -10000         0.000
-0.999       -10000         0.010
-0.998       -10000         0.011
 ...         ...             ...
0.998       -10000         0.011
0.999       -10000         0.010
 1.0        -10000         0.000
 ...         ...             ...
 -1.0        -5000         0.000
-0.999       -5000         0.050
-0.998       -5000         0.055
 ...          ...           ...
0.998       -5000         0.055
0.999       -5000         0.050
 1.0        -5000         0.000
```

Etc. In other words, the 'Time' column is sampled from [-1, 1] and the velocity is sampled from [-10000, 10000]. The Cxx value is the value of my function at the (Time,Velocity).

The problem seems to be that the values of Time and Velocity themselves often repeat, as you can see in the example. However there is only ever one unique instance of a (Time,Velocity) pair.

I would like to:

1. Plot a 3D Graph. Perhaps a mesh or surface plot with X = Time and Y = Velocity and Z = Cxx
2. Plot a heatmap in 2D, where Cxx will represent the heat value (the magnitude) and X = Time and Y = Velocity.
3. Use meshgrid to map my read-in Z values onto a grid of XY points.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Could you provide the data that you wish to plot? Or could you provide your Cxx function? You have a function with 2 variables, z = (x, y), and you wish to plot this function correct? Usually, it's expected that x, y, and z, are matrices (2D arrays). Take a look at "3D surface" from matplotlib.

Comment: Unfortunately the data is generated by something outside of python. There really isn't any function that I can apply (x,y) to and get z.